# Cassandra - Kubernetes how to keep pod ip when restart

Tags: docker, cassandra, kubernetes, cassandra-2.1

I'm using kubernetes 1.2 example to run 2 cassandra nodes for testing. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/examples/cassandra/README.md

I use daemonset to have one cassandra node by kubernetes node. Everything work fine till one cassandra node restart. IP address of the POD changes and nodetools status returns Node DOWN

```
> kubectl exec -it cassandra-lnzhj -- nodetool status fruition
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                                  Rack    
UN  10.216.1.4  25.22 MB   256     39.6%             786aede9-ec4f-4942-b52a-135bc3cd68ce  rack1
UN  10.216.0.3  2.11 MB    256     40.1%             457f7322-131a-4499-b677-4d50691207ba  rack1
DN  10.216.0.2  377.41 KB  256     38.8%             aa2ca115-e8ea-4c62-8d57-bfc5b3fabade  rack1
```

Then when i try to send a simple "select * from table;" on a keyspace with a replication factor of 2, I've this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/cqlsh", line 1093, in perform_simple_statement rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled)
File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1602, in execute result = future.result()
File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3347, in result raise self._final_exception
Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

How to keep POD IP address in order not to have Down node when Kubernetes restart it? 
Is there a better way to do it with cassandra configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this with current Kubernetes.  You need the implementation of [PetSets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18016) due in v1.3.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up this old question again but isn't it possible to keep the same IP for a container with statefulsets?

Comment: StatefulSets are the definitive name for what was initially called PetSets.

Comment: Statefulsets only allow a consistent inner cluster dns name thats also predictable/follows a naming convention. Pods in a statefulset still have dynamic IPs that changes with every time the pod is killed/reboot. A Kubernetes Service is the only thing in Kubernetes that offers a permanent static ip. You could probably hack together an implementation that uses services and statefulsets of size 1, but I suspect you'd end up with a better solution if you figured out how to get it working with dns. Also Cassandra operator (kubernetes software) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even PetSets or Stateful Sets as they are now called in Kubernetes 1.5 will not solve this problem. The new feature allows you to retain same hostname, but there are not guarantees that the ip address will remain the same. Quoting from their documentation:

> The Pods’ ordinals, hostnames, SRV records, and A record names have
>   not changed, but the IP addresses associated with the Pods may have
>   changed. In the cluster used for this tutorial, they have. This is why
>   it is important not to configure other applications to connect to Pods
>   in a StatefulSet by IP address.

If you are not tied to kubernetes and have the flexibility of choosing other solutions, [check this out](https://robinsystems.com/product-and-solutions/robin-for-databases/).

They provide a container-based solution that combines compute, network, storage, so you have full control over all resources required by cassandra, and perform snapshot/restore, scale out, scale up/down, failover, etc. And they guarantee that the same ip address and volumes are retained for a container for its entire lifetime.